# Prevent Lazarus Debugger branching into library units

Tags: debugging, lazarus, delphi

When running a Lazarus Object Pascal program in debug mode, the debugger opens up a dozen LCL library units in the IDE editor and branches to all of these units after finishing any of my event handler routines with the F4 key. How can I prevent this from happening and instead restrict the debugger to my own source code units only?

Comment: It is only my own suggestion. Compile third-party packages **without** debug info. But in this case it will be much harder to find the error source. Also use callstack window (View|Debug Windows|Call Stack) - it is very helpful.

Comment: I assume (or at least I hope) that the solution of my problem will simply be finding the right compiler/debugger/IDE option (however deeply hidden somewhere in the Lazarus menu labyrinth) to be set to the appropriate value. Unfortunately, setting the debugger option _DisableLoadSymbolsForLibraries_ didn't do the job.

Comment: That option is about loading symbols from DLLs, not for units in the EXE.  Probably it is something like tools-> configure lazarus followed by tools->build lazarus to generate a new set of units without debug info.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx to all of you who have tried to come up with an answer. But I think, in the meantime the problem has been solved. For details see:
http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,30321.0.html